# Parse time elapsed / time span / duration with several different formats

Tags: r, datetime

I need to parse time spans with several different formats, including days, hours, minutes, seconds.ms, separated by `:`: `%OS`, `%H:%OS`, `%H:%m:%OS` or `%d:%H:%m:%OS`. For example:

```
x <- c("28.6575", "1:14.0920", "1:5:38.1230", "5:23:59:38.7211")
```

The first idea that comes to mind is using `strptime` to parse the given strings as a date. This approach does not work for strings that do not contain all parts of the time span. Is it possible to turn parts of the format string to being optional?

```
strptime("5:23:59:38.7211", "%d:%H:%M:%OS")
# [1] "2015-08-05 23:59:38"
strptime("1:5:38.1230", "%d:%H:%M:%OS")
# [1] NA # wanted: "2015-08-01 01:05:38"
```

A different approach would be to turn the formatted values into seconds (e.g. `1:14.0920 ~~> 74.0920 secs`). However, I was unable to find a convenient way to do this using R.

Comment: I think you won’t get around actually parsing the string yourself, e.g. using regular expressions (or, in this simple case, via a combination of `strsplit` and `as.numeric`), and then constructing a time span from that. Incidentally, a time span is *not* a date/time, it’s the difference between two dates/times. There are some subtleties that set them apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an expanded version of @Konrad Rudolph's comment:

```
# split time spans into their different time elements
l <- strsplit(x, ":")

# pad vector with leading zeros. Here 4 is the maximum number of time elements
m <- sapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(c(rep(0, 4 - length(x)), x)))

# convert result to desired unit, e.g. seconds
m[1 , ] * 24*60*60 + m[2 , ] * 60*60 + m[3 , ] * 60 + m[4 , ]
# [1]     28.6575     74.0920   3938.1230 518378.7211
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add the missing hours, minutes, and days data.

For ex, if `v1` is your vector you could do:

```
res<-sapply(v1,function(x){
        if(str_count(x ,":")==2) paste0("1:",x)
        else if(str_count(x, ":") < 2)  paste0("1:",paste(rep("0:",2-str_count(x ,":")),collapse=""),x)
        else as.character(x)
        })
strptime(res, "%d:%H:%M:%OS")
```

It basically counts the number of colons, and adds whatever is missing to make it the right format. Days starts as 1 so I added `1:` when there was no day info.